# Erroneous encoding on form to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm receiving form data in my Spring MVC controller, but when I try to input non-ASCII characters I receive rubbish, `áéíóú` gets converted into `Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº`.

I'm using `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` in the jsp pages, Tomcat is configured to accept `UTF-8` in the URI/Connection part and the `form` is set to `acceptCharset="UTF-8"`. No idea where to look into next.

I'm testing on Firefox 38.0 in Ubuntu 14.04. The server is in Ubuntu 14.04 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an encoding filter to your web.xml to make it encode the chars correctly:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the UTF-8 text is being read as latin1 encoding, which uses only one byte per char (for example, á (hex value `C3 A1`) is read as two latin1 chars `Ã¡` (hex values `C3` and `A1`)).

You can check the HTML output if it has the `<meta>` tag on the `<head>` section:

`<meta charset="utf-8" />` (if you´re using HTML5 `DOCTYPE`).

Comment: Yes. For earlier HTML, use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Nah, none works, might it be because its Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Try a simple static HTML only page being served from Tomcat with an accent and the above tag.

Comment: Every page gets served as `"text/html;charset=UTF-8"` even without the `meta` tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029269/utf-8-encoding-with-form-post-and-spring-controller see the accepted answer.