# spring boot + thymeleaf cannot correctly encode UTF-8 characters form POST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, encoding, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am evaluating spring boot with thymeleaf template engine. I am facing the problem of UTF8 character form posting problem.

For the simplest `form.html` post example :

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>

<form th:action="@{/test/doPost}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  @RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showForm() {
    return "test/form";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/doPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String doPost(@RequestBody String body,
                       @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
    logger.info("body = {}", body);
    logger.info("name = {}", name);
    return "redirect:/test/form";
  }
}
```

Spring MVC (or thymeleaf) cannot correctly encode form with UTF-8 character in this example.

If I input `ä` , I'll see this log :

```
TestController - body = name=%C3%83%C2%A4
TestController - name = Ã¤
```

`ä` should be encoded to `%C3%A4` . the body should be `name=%C3%A4` , but I don't know why it becomes `%C3%83%C2%A4` and decoded to wrong characters.

I googled and found some solutions , such as adding an encoding filter :

```
  @Bean
  public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    return characterEncodingFilter;
  }
```

But not working.

Another solution is to `thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` by this way :

```
  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return templateResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    return springTemplateEngine;
  }

  @Bean
  public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine());
    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
  }
```

But it doesn't work , either.

Moreover , `ThymeleafViewResolver`'s characterEncoding is already set in the [ThymeleafAutoConfiguration source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java#L211) . There seems no need to re-define `UTF-8` here.

It seems I have similar situation with this question : [UTF-8 encoding with form post and Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16064963/298430) . The accepted solution is

> Moving CharacterEncodingFilter to the top and forcing the encoding to
>   be set as UTF-8 solved the problem.

I tried this :

```
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
    registrationBean.setOrder(0);
    return registrationBean;
  }
```

But still not working.

I think UTF-8 form posting is very basic , but why it just cannot work here . Did I miss anything ?

environment :

```
<springboot.version>1.3.0.M5</springboot.version>
<spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Thanks a lot.

*A little off-topic : I've used many other frameworks , such as JSP/wicket/grails/play1/play2 , non of these have such annoying UTF-8 situation.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is a known issue, already fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3912) - the fix will be shipped with Spring Boot 1.3.0.RC1.

In the meantime, you can work around the problem by declaring the encoding filter manually:

```
@Autowired
private HttpEncodingProperties httpEncodingProperties;

@Bean
public OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
    OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter filter = new OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding(this.httpEncodingProperties.getCharset().name());
    filter.setForceEncoding(this.httpEncodingProperties.isForce());
    filter.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. Hope 1.3.0.RC1 will be released soon.